# ExtJs Table layout border missing and cell color

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to design a simple risk assessment matrix in ExtJs but facing two problems.

1. border is missing for the cells with combobox in it.
2. I want to set the whole cell background red. not just a part of it.

Please look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2h07) for better explanation.

Comment: can you explain this *whole cell background red* ?

Comment: If you have a look at the fiddle only the text part of the cell's background is changed to red. I want the whole cell to be red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `border` you need to use config [`tdAttrs`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.layout.container.Table.html#cfg-tdAttrs) and for change background color of particular cell you need to use [`cellCls`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.layout.container.Table.html)

In [this Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2h0f), I have created a demo using your code and used `tdAttrs` and `cellCls`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {

    name: 'myContainer',
    id: 'myContainer',

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        title: 'Assessment',
        name: 'assessmentPanel',
        id: 'assessmentPanel',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            tdAttrs: {
                style: {
                    border: '1px solid #ccc'
                }
            },
            // The total column count must be specified here
            columns: 5
        },
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            bodyStyle: 'padding:30px',
            html: 'Risk',
            scroll: false,
            //border: true

            //margin: '0 15 0 0'
        },
        items: [{
            html: '<font color="white">Risk</font>',
            //cellCls: 'first-row',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (view) {
                    console.log('view config entered!!');
                    //this.up('view').addCls('first-row');
                    //view.addCls('first-row');
                }
            }

        }, {
            html: '<b>Consequence</b>'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Likelihood</b>'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Risk</b>'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Service Interruption</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment1',
            id: 'assessment1',
            cellCls: 'demo',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            cls: 'bg-trasparent',
            value: 'red',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Red',
                    value: 'red'
                }, {
                    text: 'Gray',
                    value: 'gray'
                }, {
                    text: 'Green',
                    value: 'green'
                }, {
                    text: 'Yellow',
                    value: 'yellow'
                }, {
                    text: 'Blue',
                    value: 'blue'
                }]
            }),
            listeners: {
                select: function (combo, record) {
                    combo.el.dom.closest('td').style.background = record.get('value')
                }
            }
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Revenue Growth</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment2',
            id: 'assessment2',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Reputation</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment3',
            id: 'assessment3',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Legal and Compliance</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment4',
            id: 'assessment4',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Capital Items</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment5',
            id: 'assessment5',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Financial</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment6',
            id: 'assessment6',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            height: 5,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'

        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Highest Risk</b>'
        }, {
            html: 'Minor'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'

        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }]
    }]
});
```

**CSS CODE**

```
<style>
    .demo {
        background: red;
    }

    .noborder {
        border: 0px !important;
    }

    .bg-trasparent input {
        background: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Hey @N.Jadhav is there any way I can get the combobox color go red too?

Comment: And how can I change the color of the cell OnChange (from  the listeneres change:). Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do on `change/select` of combo-box using `combo.el.dom.closest('td').style.background = record.get('value')` . I have updated my answer. You can also check here [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2h0f).

Comment: Hey Jadhav Thank you so much. you are a really big help. Is there any way I can get the combobox colored too? I mean it looks odd when the background is red and a white rectangle combobox. Red background and red combobox would look good. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShezRatnani yes you can do using `background: transparent;` for combo input cls. I have updated answer and [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2h0f) as well. Please check.

Comment: Hello I feel like you can help me with this issue. please refer to this question:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570759/extjs-acting-differently-on-different-browsers

Comment: I have provided answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570759/extjs-acting-differently-on-different-browsers) please check