# ExtJs acting differently on different browsers

Tags: extjs

I have a simple risk assessment matrix built in a table layout. I have listeners which change the background color of that cell accordingly. It works exactly how I want it to in chrome. But not working fine in Internet Explorer.

Please look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2h0f&view/editor) for better explanation.

*Here is my code:-*

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {

    name: 'myContainer',
    id: 'myContainer',

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        title: 'Assessment',
        name: 'assessmentPanel',
        id: 'assessmentPanel',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            tdAttrs: {
                style: {
                    border: '1px solid #ccc'
                }
            },
            // The total column count must be specified here
            columns: 5
        },
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            bodyStyle: 'padding:30px',
            html: 'Risk',
            scroll: false,
            //border: true

            //margin: '0 15 0 0'
        },
        items: [{
            html: '<font color="white">Risk</font>',
            //cellCls: 'first-row',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function(view) {
                    console.log('view config entered!!');
                    //this.up('view').addCls('first-row');
                    //view.addCls('first-row');
                }
            }

        }, {
            html: '<b>Consequence</b>'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Likelihood</b>'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Risk</b>'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Service Interruption</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment1',
            id: 'assessment1',
            cellCls: 'demo',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            cls: 'bg-trasparent',
            value: 'red',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Red',
                    value: 'red'
                }, {
                    text: 'Gray',
                    value: 'gray'
                }, {
                    text: 'Green',
                    value: 'green'
                }, {
                    text: 'Yellow',
                    value: 'yellow'
                }, {
                    text: 'Blue',
                    value: 'blue'
                }]
            }),
            listeners: {
                select: function(combo, record) {
                    combo.el.dom.closest('td').style.background = record.get('value')
                }
            }
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Revenue Growth</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment2',
            id: 'assessment2',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Reputation</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment3',
            id: 'assessment3',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Legal and Compliance</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment4',
            id: 'assessment4',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Capital Items</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment5',
            id: 'assessment5',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Financial</b>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'assessment6',
            id: 'assessment6',
            value: 'Minor',
            width: 130,
            height: 5,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'text',
            valueField: 'value',
            editable: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                data: [{
                    text: 'Minor',
                    value: 'minor'
                }, {
                    text: 'Moderate',
                    value: 'moderate'
                }, {
                    text: 'Major',
                    value: 'major'
                }, {
                    text: 'Severe',
                    value: 'severe'
                }]
            })
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'

        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            height: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: '<b>Highest Risk</b>'
        }, {
            html: 'Minor'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'

        }, {
            width: 20,
            cellCls: 'noborder'
        }, {
            html: 'Cell F content'
        }]
    }]
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: which version of IE you are using ?

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 11 version : 11.0.9600.19002CO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) doesn't support IE so you can use also use the [`Ext.dom.Element.up('td')`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-up) to get the required result.

- **Ext.dom.Element.up** walks up the dom looking for a parent node that matches the passed simple selector (e.g. `div.some-class` or `span:first-child`). This is a shortcut for `findParentNode()` that always returns an `Ext.dom.Element`

I have updated this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2h0f)** and I have tested in **IE-11** it's working fine.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'assessment1',
    id: 'assessment1',
    cellCls: 'demo',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'value',
    editable: false,
    cls: 'bg-trasparent',
    value: 'red',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        data: [{
            text: 'Red',
            value: 'red'
        }, {
            text: 'Gray',
            value: 'gray'
        }, {
            text: 'Green',
            value: 'green'
        }, {
            text: 'Yellow',
            value: 'yellow'
        }, {
            text: 'Blue',
            value: 'blue'
        }]
    }),
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, record) {
            var el = combo.el;
            el.up('td').setStyle('background', record.get('value'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

IE does not have the "closest" method,

Change This:

```
combo.el.dom.closest('td').style.background = record.get('value')
```

By this:

```
combo.el.dom.parentElement.style.background = record.get('value')
```

Comment: Also, please note that you are leaving ExtJS wherever you access the `dom`.

Comment: Agree with what @Alexander said, you should use [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html) methods to avoid any browser quirks. So change the line that @Fabio mentioned with this: `combo.getEl().up('td').setStyle('backgroundColor', record.get('value'));`. Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2hbf&view/editor

Comment: @Fabio your answer does work but according to what Alexander said Scebotari's answer is a better option but considering that he answerd it as a comment. I would have to accept N. Jadhav's answer as he also have wrote the full code in his answer so if one day Sencha's fiddle go down the question and answer should still make sense. I have still upvoted your answer as it works. Thanks for the help everyone.